IE compatibility mode in Microsoft Edge is not working in Windows 11 using Selenium Java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerOptions;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        ieOptions.attachToEdgeChrome();
        ieOptions.withEdgeExecutablePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);
        driver.get("http://www.bing.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_q")).sendKeys("Elon Musk");
    }
}

When I executed the provided code, the web browser successfully launched via selenium and navigated to Bing.com. However, the browser then become unresponsive, failing to focus on the search field and input "Elon Musk". Consequently, the code threw the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '23.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Command: [f149ad19-2825-4c0d-a9fb-539b4a1130bb, get {url=http://www.bing.com}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.edgechromium: true, ie.edgepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ie.ignoreprocessmatch: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: true, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:15552/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: f149ad19-2825-4c0d-a9fb-539b4a1130bb
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:558)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:295)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: NettyHttpHandler request execution error
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:76)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:48)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:15552 after 180000 ms
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.wrapInExecutionException(CompletableFuture.java:345)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:440)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2140)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:59)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:15552 after 180000 ms
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.TimeoutTimerTask.expire(TimeoutTimerTask.java:43)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.RequestTimeoutTimerTask.run(RequestTimeoutTimerTask.java:50)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:715)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ImmediateExecutor.execute(ImmediateExecutor.java:34)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:703)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:790)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:503)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1575)

Browser shouldn't be unresponsive and input the the provided text

This is protected mode settings issue of security zones Of Internet Explorer.
In the context of security zones for Internet Explorer (IE) automation using Selenium in Java, it's essential to ensure that Protected Mode settings are consistent across all zones. In Windows 11, Protected Mode is set only for Zone 1 by default.
By default, the following five zones are defined:
0: My Computer

1: Local Intranet Zone

2: Trusted Sites Zone

3: Internet Zone

4: Restricted Sites Zone

Note: Protected Mode for each zone is typically set from Internet Options. By default, "My Computer" does not appear in the Zone box on the Security tab, as it is locked down to help improve security.
Protected Mode settings must be consistent across all zones. If they are not, you will encounter the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. 

Given that Microsoft has discontinued IE, Protected Mode settings have been removed from Internet Options in Windows 11. Thus, you can enable Protected Mode using the registry. To do so, create or set a DWORD named 2500 for Protected Mode. A value of 0 means Protected Mode is enabled, while a value of 3 means it is disabled.
Here are the steps to create the Protected Mode DWORD:
Press Windows + R to open the Run window.

Type regedit.

Press Enter.

Navigate to the following path: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones

For Zone 1, DWORD 2500 is already created. Update its value to 0.

Click on Zone 2.

Right-click in the right panel, select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value.

Set the name to 2500 and the value to 0.

Repeat steps 6 to 8 for all other zones.

